# error in swift - expressions not allowed at the top level

Tags: swift

[any idea about this error?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phmzH.png)

still not on the issue but not sure what does it mean that the expression is not allowed at the top level, any idea? I am learning swift and taking a long time to understand the issues, thank you all in advance!
bzm.

Comment: This has been [covered many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+expressions+not+allowed+at+top+level). Also, please post code as text, not as pictures. Pictures can't be searched or referenced.

Comment: You can't put code "anywhere". Except in "scripts/playground", where the code/instructions can be read "from top to bottom" (to simplify). You are in a `UIViewController`, so put that code inside a method of that class.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.

1. You are trying to run code outside a class in an App project. Try playground.
2. You deleted the base code for the ViewController class for the class to run.

You cannot run code outside a struct/class in your app's source code. This only works in playground but not in an App file. Try the code in a Playground file and you won't run into any errors. Playground is used to learn Swift. What you are trying to do is, running the code in an Project App in Xcode and there are certain conditions while doing that.

Playground files support the execution of top-level code. Code within a playground file is order-dependent, run in top-down lexical order.

A Swift app is composed of any number of files, each with the functions, classes, and other declarations that make up the app. Most Swift files in your app are order-independent, meaning you can use a type before it is defined, and can even import modules at the bottom of the file (although that is not recommended Swift style.)

However, top-level code is not allowed in most of your Swift source files. For clarity, any executable statement not written within a function body, within a class, or otherwise encapsulated is considered top-level. We have this rule because if top-level code were allowed in all your files, it would be hard to determine where to start the program.

Read https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7

From what I can gather from the image, you have written the code in the ViewController file of an App project. An app needs a starting point for the code to run, and when you create a new UIKit project in Xcode, it automatically creates a ViewController class and assigns it as the initial point. UIViewControllers need certain code to execute. You had deleted the base code and tried to run your code.

You can check out my example below to understand. When you run the App, the ViewController is created(since it is the initial point right now as mentioned before) and its view is brought onto screen(read about View lifecycle for viewcontrollers). The app then executes whatever is in the `viewDidLoad()` function of the ViewController once the view is loaded. Your code in that function will now execute.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let headers = [
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer 87c2d6d21b7cacdb68efa966d34efcbc"
    ]
    
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/authentication")!                         as URL,
                                    cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        makeRequest()
    }
    
    func makeRequest() {
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response,error) -> Void in
            
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error as Any)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print (httpResponse)
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

However, I suggest you initialise a struct/class in your app file and write this code there. I suggest you create a new file in your file directory of the app and name it NetworkService and call it's function in your ViewController file. ViewController should contain minimal code related to tasks other than UI.

Also, please try to add code using as text instead of image. Use the markdown provided to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in Swift ***Expressions not allowed at the top level*** error comes when you use the expressions or statements that is not within the context of any function or class or other appropriate scope,
so use functions or a class to define the expressions or statements to fix this issue.

```
import Foundation

func makeAPIRequest() {
    let headers = [
        "accept": "application/ison",
        "Authorization": "Bearer 87c2d6d21b7cacdb68efa966d34efcbc"
    ]
    
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/authentication")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print(httpResponse)
            }
        }
    }
    
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

***use case:***
call the function in the ***ViewDidLoad*** of the ViewController like below

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
          makeAPIRequest()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Hope this will fix your issue